# extracting data from .txt file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a txt file which contains the following information

```
03/05/2016 3020 04/05/2016 1605 05/05/2016 2015 06/05/2016 1014 07/05/2016 558 08/05/2016 509 09/05/2016 1510 10/05/2016 1010
```

I want to extract this data form this txt file and store it in an variable in python..
How can i achieve this...
I am using pyth

Comment: Why did a Google search on reading files in python reveal?

Comment: Is it one long line?

Comment: it is multilple long line

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f=open('myfile.txt','r')

myvar=f.read()
```

That gives you all the text but it also returns text formating characters like new line,tab etc.

To avoid new lines do

```
myvar=''.join(f.read().split('\n'))
```

Comment: i dont want the text formatting characters

Comment: How can i achieve this

Comment: Then do myvar=''.join(f.read().split('\n')) to erase new line characters. You are spliting the text where you find a newline,that returns a list which you join with the empty string

Comment: Thank U...............

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('filepath', 'r+')

text = txt.read()

print text
```

where 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing.

Comment: Thank u ................

Comment: if answer was useful please upvote the answer.